80's/90's Summer Camp movie that was BADLY dubbed?
When I was younger back in like 2000-2005 ish I had this summer camp movie that I watched over and over but I can't remember the title. 
It was either dubbed over or the lips didn't match the audio. There were two sides of a camp that these families had RVs in. The kids were kind of split into these two different groups among themselves that fought and had booby traps and everything against each other. 
A girl and a guy from the opposite camps fell in love with each other and would meet in private. They got caught by the groups and were punished in some way?? 
There was also a fish catching scene that was a competition by the camps or groups or whatever and one of the small boats of kids were selling bait. 
They had a judicial system and everything for the kid groups. 
At the end there's a giant forest fire?? 

Welcome to Movies & TV! Please try to add anything that may help identification. When was it released? Was it in Color or Black & White? What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions.

There's a good chance it was dubbed into multiple languages, and some might have been worse than others. Which language did you see it it, and do you have any idea what language it originally was in?

This is only a guess since you say the movie was Dubbed because the lips weren't synced to the audio. I don't know if this means that it was a dubbed foreign movie or the audio was just badly synced in your copy.
However, this seems exactly like the plot of Cheaper by the Dozen 2 (2005). 
It matches when you saw it, but it is not from the 80s/90s.

The Bakers, while on vacation, find themselves competing with a rival family of eight children.

Some details:

It is about a vacations with two competing families
There is a couple formed by one teen from each family
There is this moment:


Sarah Baker is caught shoplifting in a gift shop, and Mark accidentally sets off a backpack of fireworks, causing widespread panic, especially when the backpack is thrown into a boat, igniting its engine and causing it to explode.

Some of the other details I can only be sure by re-watching the movie.



